# Cadê a opção de rejeitar por "edição insuficiente"?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

Estou louco ou a opção de rejeitar por "edição insuficiente" sumiu? É um das coisas que mais acontecem em edições.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17177 :D Quem não tem cão caça com gato. Diria que é bug mesmo.

Comment: Não é bug, @bigown, é by-design.

Comment: É, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039, pode ter sido bom, embora vai ter gente achando que qualquer edição mínima agora pode ser aceita. Trocamos de problema.

Comment: Tem uns casos em que ainda não está claro como rejeitar, @bigown. Mas por enquanto o Shog está batendo pé na mudança que ele propôs (com razão, afinal se acabou de mudar é preciso testar um pouco pra ver se vai dar certo ou não).

Comment: +1 por suscitar a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com a [alteração que introduziu os botões de editar+aprovar e editar+rejeitar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039), esse motivo foi considerado obsoleto. Isso ainda é um pouco polêmico ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/what-should-be-used-in-place-of-too-minor), [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion)), mas pelo que entendi vão insistir nesse caminho para ver se dá certo.

A lógica é: se a edição é "insuficiente", em primeiro lugar você deve resolver o problema, e fazer uma edição que seja melhor – ou pelo menos "suficiente". Com os novos botões você poderá decidir se a edição original será considerada aprovada ou rejeitada.

Se a edição não acrescentar nada válido (por exemplo, apenas adicionar formatação aleatória), rejeite como vandalismo. Infelizmente há outros casos, que ainda estão no limbo. Se não vir o que editar e nenhum motivo enlatado servir, use um motivo personalizado.

Comment: Ficamos esclarecidos :)

Comment: Eu não entendi a lógica do "Editar e rejeitar". Faz sentido melhorar a edição ou rejeitá-la de vez. Mas porque eu melhoraria uma edição para então rejeitá-la em seguida?

Comment: @Andrey Essa opção já existia, quando você escolhia editar tinha um checkbox no final pra você informar se a edição original era útil ou não. É a mesma coisa: se o post tem algo a ser editado, mas a edição que o levou para a fila de análise era muito ruim, opte por rejeitar.

Comment: Agora entendi. Acho que do jeito que estava antes (com o *checkbox*) era mais claro.