# Usuários que editam muitas perguntas

Tags: debate, edição, edições-sugeridas

Hoje apareceram 7 edições de perguntas para analisar na minha grade de análises, em quase todas perguntas o editor havia alterado apenas uma palavra que estava errada na pergunta, no caso, a palavra "Duvida" -> Alterada para -> "Dúvida". Na edição da pergunta ainda havia o comentário: "acentuação".

A meu ver não houve mudança significativa no entendimento da pergunta, também não creio que o usuário foi mal intencionado, mas qual a posição da rede SO nesses casos? Deve-se aceitar qualquer tipo de edições mesmo que não se altere em nada o entendimento da mesma?

Comment: Pode ser [**isso**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2464/13412).

Comment: Talvez, mas mudar apenas uma palavra que não altere em nada o entendimento da pergunta? Sei la, quando ha muitos erros tudo bem, as vezes pegamos cada pergunta que da ate vontade de ficar cego... mas um misero u -> ú em uma pergunta com mais de 800 palavras não me parece uma grande justificativa..

Comment: Sim, o principio era que a alteração deveria 'incrementar' sentido ou corrigir um erro, mas foram aceitas as edições de palavras incorretas, então que seja apenas uma boa pratica.

Comment: Relacionado: [Existe algum ação a ser tomada quando existe um comportamento de “caça de reputação/medalhas”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1612/3117).

Comment: Reverti o ultimo edit, pois tirou o foco original de **edições em série**. A postagem é antiga, e sugiro quem não acompanhou a evolução do site ler os links e assuntos relacionados. Edição de coisas pequenas tem outras consequências, e apesar de por si só serem de alguma forma boas, tem que tomar cuidado para não deixar passar uma série de outros problemas (além de ficar pondo coisas problemáticas na home do site e na fila de reabertura indevidamente). Sobre edições pequenas já tem outros posts https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1952/ e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1180 e outras mais

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Eu não acho isso ruim. Muito pelo contrário, aplaudo e apoio a iniciativa.

Se tem alguém por aí que decidiu dedicar tempo gratuitamente e de boa vontade para corrigir todas as ocorrências que encontrou de um determinado erro de digitação, acentuação, ortografia, etc, então acho que todos só teríamos a agradecer por isso.

Depois que o usuário atingir 2000 pontos de reputação, as alterações dele são aprovadas automaticamente e não vão para a fila de análise. Então depois disso, se ele estiver corrigindo erros de acentuação e ortografia por aí por menor que sejam, pouca gente irá perceber, mas isso não significa que este deixará de ser um grandioso trabalho.

Então se o usuário editou, por menor que seja a alteração e a edição foi correta, clique em "aceitar" e veja a próxima. Se tiver mais algo a melhorar, pode clicar em "aceitar e melhorar".

Aliás, acabei de editar esta sua pergunta principalmente por causa da acentuação. Oh, ironia. :)

Comment: concordo plenamente, o trabalho cooperativo é assim (:
isso so melhora a qualidade da comunidade.

Comment: @Victor Stafusa a pontuação é de 2000 pontos

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Isso é porque na época que escrevi isso, eram apenas 1000 pontos porque o site era beta. Depois que o site graduou é que passou a ser 2000. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo aviso, já editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 10):

Eu faço isso direto. Acho importantíssimo corrigir mesmo se for apenas uma acentuação ou uma vírgula. Para falantes do português parece insignificante mas para um estrangeiro que quer traduzir o texto num tradutor online ou mesmo consultar num dicionário, fica bem complicado principalmente quando o erro gramatical traz outro sentido.

Você pode ainda indagar se há mesmo estrangeiros que consultam páginas técnicas em português. Sim, existem. Nem tudo encontramos em sites em inglês ou no nosso próprio idioma. Eu costumo consultar sites em idiomas diversos diferentes do inglês e do português. Quando a gramática é mal feita, os tradutores online não ajudam muito e você fica sem entender muito bem o que o texto diz.