# Eleições para Moderador 2018 - Questionário

Tags: debate, eleição

Essa é a sessão de perguntas e respostas para os candidatos à moderador do Stack Overflow em Português. As perguntas enviadas [na última quinta-feira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7330/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2018-cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas) estão listadas aqui, para que os candidatos possam respondê-las.

Nem todas as perguntas foram compiladas — como denotado anteriormente, só selecionámos as perguntas enviadas pela comunidade com mais votos, para além do conjunto por defeito da nossa parte, para um total de 10 perguntas.

Os candidatos devem responder esse post, listando cada pergunta do questionário e a sua resposta. Para ajudar, as perguntas estão pré-formatadas como citações e com espaço entre elas, para sua resposta. Basta copiar tudo [depois da linha divisória](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/36f9e9eb-883d-4f53-8377-762c3a2a84d0/view-source). Lembrem-se também de colocar seu nome no **topo** do seu post, para que todo mundo possa saber quem é *antes* de ler tudo que você escreveu.

Depois que todos responderem, esse tópico será um registro das ideias e propostas de cada candidato e vai aparecer na perfil de cada um na página da eleição.

Boa sorte!

**Ah, e quando tiveres completado a tua resposta, por favor fornece um link para a mesma depois desta porção de texto, antes do conjunto de três travessões. Por favor deixa a lista de links de acordo com a ordem em que as respostas foram apresentadas.**

Para poupar no scroll, aqui estão os links para as respostas de cada candidato (pela ordem em que foram apresentadas):

- [Victor Stafusa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7373/132)
- [Bacco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7374/70)
- [sam](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7375/8063)
- [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7376/5878)
- [Felipe Augusto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7384/71065)
- [Ricardo Pontual](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7385/57220)
- [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7386/3635)

---

> 1. É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?
> 2. Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?
> 3. Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.
> 4. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
> 5. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?
> 6. Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?
> 7. Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?
> 8. É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.
> 9. Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?
> 10. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Comment: adicionei minhas respostas, um pouco atrasado.. rs

Answer (score 25):

[image: 1]

## Breve apresentação e respostas do [Bacco](/users/70/bacco):

> **Carlos Bacco**
>
> - Programador, profissional de TI e de comunicação por 30 anos;
> - formado em Direito pela Universidade Metodista de Piracicaba;
> - participa do site desde a sua fundação, antes do beta público;
> - quarto usuário mais pontuado do site do placar geral (mais de 80.400 pontos);
> - relação média de pontos por pergunta maior que 70 pontos;
> - ouro nas tags [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) e [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql);
> - Presença e participação constante no site, site meta, chat.

Como é muito texto, tentei ser objetivo e sucinto, mas caso ainda restem duvidas, me pergunte!

Lá vai! :D

> <sub>**1.** É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?</sub>

Minha experiência na rede me mostrou que o maior problema é a percepção da ferramenta, então em vez de tentar convencer as pessoas a mudarem de atitude prefiro tentar trazer o problema verdadeiro à tona.

Em vez de tentar combater fechamentos e negativos, melhor explicar para os novos usuários que são ocorrências naturais, mostrando como resolver os problemas das postagens.

No SOpt os problemas com veteranos são bem pontuais, e eventuais falhas de diálogo precisam de uma mínima intervenção, porém, "cirúrgica". O segredo é a sensibilidade para dar o empurrãozinho que falta para o lado certo.

> <sub>**2.** Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?</sub>

Moderador é justamente aquele que foge do "suporte técnico". O ponto aqui é o fator humano. A parte técnica já é gerenciada pelo mecanismo do site, o moderador é aquele que compensa as parte onde o sistema não resolveu.

Quanto à cultura, tem-se que tomar cuidado. Temos a cultura que tornou o site o que é hoje, e isso vem de longa data, e tem a percepção que as pessoas tem desta cultura. O moderador precisa conhecer as duas coisas, para fazer com que a percepção dos usuários se aproxime da realidade.

A "técnica" consiste em saber engraxar essas engrenagens para o mecanismo funcionar com o mínimo possível de atrito.

> <sub>**3.** Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.</sub>

Como presença constante no site, já conheço o peso no dia a dia (e até a rejeição em alguns momentos por contrariar algumas expectativas individuais e pouco realistas). O que vai mudar no meu caso específico em sendo eleito, é basicamente o rol de ferramentas disponíveis.

Claro que proporcionalmente a "dor de cabeça" aumenta, mas nada que eu não esteja acostumado. Dos meus mais de 40 anos de idade, desde representante de classe (por aclamação) até cargos gerenciais lidando com funcionários, saber balancear a postura do cara legal que serve de exemplo com a do cara que vai ter que por a mão na massa para fazer a parte ingrata é algo que já tive que aprender faz muito tempo.

> <sub>**4.** Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?</sub>

Como já respondido nos comentários da fase de candidatura, basicamente seguindo o roteiro óbvio, do diálogo antes de mais nada. Muitas vezes basta compreender o que leva o usuário a ter atitude tóxica, e dialogar sobre isso.

Alguns casos mais extremos infelizmente não tem jeito (de tempos em tempos aparece um desses). Aí, realmente são necessárias as ferramentas de moderação. Mas qualquer pessoa de bom senso sabe que não pode ser à toa, até porque, se chegarmos nesse ponto dificilmente vai partir de uma decisão individual.

Não queremos afastar nenhum usuário, mas quando se tratar de conflito entre uma pessoa que tem um comportamento adequado e outra(s) que não, não há conteúdo bom de respostas (nem pageviews) que justifiquem deixarmos passar uma injustiça.

Além disso, a licença do site é muito clara, o conteúdo vai continuar aqui. E sempre teremos boas pessoas para responder se o ambiente for saudável. Não dá para dizer o mesmo se incentivarmos quem é tóxico.

> <sub>**5.** Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?</sub>

Da mesma forma que a pergunta anterior, onde há desentendimento, precisa-se de diálogo, e eventualmente trazer mais moderadores e representantes da rede para o este diálogo. Basicamente estou respondendo esta pergunta para considerar cenários hipotéticos, afinal as coisas mudam, e as pessoas às vezes tem seus momentos estranhos.

O fato é que com o rol que temos hoje de moderadores, o diálogo sempre foi muito fácil, e se tudo correr bem nesta eleição, continuará sendo.

> <sub>**6.** Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?</sub>

Praticamente todos tem "mais experiência" que os outros em uma ou outra coisa. Seria muita prepotência não enxergar isso. Cada ação tem uma motivação, é nosso papel entender isto - o que é completamente independente das regras do site. Estas tem que ser seguidas e é o nosso "contrato", com a rede e a comunidade.

Experiência, pontos, tempo de casa não podem influenciar nisso, salvo quando trazem melhores resultados. Nunca como justificadiva para não se fazer o que tem que ser feito.

> <sub>**7.** Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?</sub>

Reputação nunca foi meu foco primordial. Aconteceu pela dedicação. Sempre prezei por uma boa relação de pontos/resposta, e não para o score total.

A satisfação está em atingir o objetivo. O site é um meio, e não um fim. A moderação serve para que esse meio cumpra com o objetivo.

> <sub>**8.** É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.</sub>

Simplesmente eu já não estaria aqui, se fosse olhar por este lado. Tanto que passei por duas eleições, com incentivo para ser candidato por parte de alguns colegas, e nem tentei nada para evitar assumir uma tarefa que não tinha como me dedicar naquele momento, caso eleito.

Hoje estou participando do processo por ter posto os pesos na balança e concluído que posso fazer o que é proposto.

> <sub>**9.** Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?</sub>

No ítem 3 já detalhei um bocado isto, o fato é que nos horários mais diversos em que estou presente, encontro situações onde as ferramentas poderiam me ajudar melhor. Meu lado de usuário vai continuar existindo na hora de responder e de votar (muita gente esquece que o voto positivo e negativo do moderador funciona igual o de qualquer usuário normal).

Agora, se há uma eleição, é porque a necessidade de um moderador surgiu. E, se surgiu, alguém tem que ocupar o espaço. Simplesmente eu acredito ser uma pessoa qualificada para isto, então, cá estou.

> <sub>**10.** Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?</sub>

Não pretendo ser tão diferente dos demais moderadores, provavelmente a maior diferença mesmo vai ser no horário de atuação (até porque, a função é a mesma). O que eu tenho a agregar é minha individualidade, e talvez até uma facilidade em não temer reações adversas.

Sobre os problemas da rede, não tenho tantas expectativas de mudar como moderador, quem sabe como usuário que questiona, talvez algo mude. "Mudar a rede" nem é função do moderador, para começo de conversa. Ajudar a conduzir, sim.

Só para não deixar de falar em mudança: já identifiquei uma série de problemas que parece que a rede não tem interesse em intervir ou mudar. Quem sabe se for eleito, o diálogo melhore com o staff e possamos subir um pouco o nível da conversa, mas isto é mero efeito colateral.

Estou à sua disposição, não hesite em questionar! Tão importante quanto o voto é você estar satifeito com a sua decisão, seja qual for.

Answer (score 18):

## Anderson Carlos Woss

- Brasileiro nato, do interior do Paraná, morador de Curitiba;
- Engenheiro eletrônico, formado pela Universidade Tecnológica Federal do Paraná;
- Mestrado, não concluído, em fotônica pela mesma instituição;
- Atua principalmente nas linguagens web;
- Provavelmente uma das pessoas mais calmas que irá conhecer :D
- Python ♥

---

> 1. É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?

Para quem é mais ativo no site sabe que a grande maioria dessas perguntas são, de fato, de usuários novos. Os casos em que o usuário já conhece bem o funcionamento do site e mesmo assim criam perguntas de baixa qualidade são caso pontuais e devem ser tratados sem generalização. Para os usuários novos, percebo que muitas vezes mesmo fazendo o tour o usuário chega até o formulário de perguntar não entendendo direito como funciona a comunidade. O próprio tour é mais marketing que busca fazer com que o usuário se interesse pelo site do que instruí-lo quanto ao funcionamento. Isso talvez deverá ser revisto. Uma publicação no Meta detalhando melhor como a comunidade funciona com uma linguagem mais acessível aos novos usuários pode se mostrar mais efetivo que o próprio tour. O fato é que se de alguma forma o novo usuário chegar ao formulário para perguntar já sabendo como fazer não teremos com o que nos preocupar no período pós-pergunta. Hoje já contamos com alguns comentários *enlatados* para a grande maioria das situações que podem ser utilizados. Eles são simples e diretos. Sempre melhor elaborar algum comentário para cada situação, conversando diretamente com o usuário; isso se mostra mais efetivo que os comentários enlatados, mas quando esses comentários começam a ficar intolerantes ou até agressivos eu aconselharia o usuário (aquele que comentou) a se afastar, deixar de atuar nesse quesito por um tempo, até esfriar a cabeça. Não adianta ser agressivo, então deixe que outros usuários orientem o novo usuário.

Essa é a grande magia de uma comunidade como a nossa: você não precisa reger a comunidade sozinho. Se você, como usuário experiente, perceber que está começando a ficar intolerante/agressivo em algumas situações se afaste e esfrie a cabeça, deixe que outros o façam. Você não precisa comentar em tudo, não precisa votar em tudo. Quanto mais ativo melhor, mas não vamos exagerar.

> 2. Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?
> 3. Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

A pergunta 3 basicamente responde a pergunta 2, que resume-se ao fato de que um moderador não resolve apenas questões técnicas da comunidade, mas, pelo contrário, ele deve suprir as deficiências da mesma. Em qualquer lugar que você ter "fator humano" como principal quesito, você terá problemas; se em um pequeno grupo de semelhantes que possuem exatamente o mesmo ponto de vista é somente uma questão de tempo para alguém discordar e começar uma discussão, imagina em um grupo de quase 100.000 pessoas. É natural que ideias contrárias às suas surjam a todo momento e saber gerenciar isso faz com que uma comunidade cresça. Acredito que atualmente, no Stack Overflow em Português, estejamos num tamanho que eu consideraria o "início do ideal". Temos uma quantidade de usuários suficientes para gerar publicações de excelência em todas as áreas dentro da abrangência do site, mas essa quantidade não chega a ser grande a ponto de perdemos o controle. De fato, esse é o ponto que deverá ser discutido, pois crescer, mesmo em número de usuários, é fundamental, e temos que fazer isso sem perder o controle.

Temos que fazer com que nossos usuários sintam-se engajados com a comunidade, mas não só isso, que os usuários sejam comprometidos com a qualidade. Esse é nosso grande diferencial. Nós contamos com a maior comunidade de profissionais da área no Brasil, o uso no site é completamente gratuito, precisamos tirar benefícios disso. Temos a liberdade, por exemplo, de gerar conteúdo muito melhor que a própria documentação oficial de alguma tecnologia. Isso não é para qualquer um.

Obviamente que será questão de tempo alguém discordar de mim como moderador. Dificilmente alguém gosta de ser contrariado, principalmente quando, enquanto moderador, será minha opinião contra a dele. A questão será o diálogo. Serei aberto a qualquer tipo de discussão sobre o site, seja porque discordou de algo que fiz, seja de outro moderador, outro usuário, etc. Basta lembrar que discutir não é brigar. Como moderador eu irei errar, cedo ou tarde, e nem é papel do moderador ser perfeito - nem de ninguém - mas caberá a mim ser humilde e assumir o erro nessas horas, buscando aprender com a situação para não cometer o mesmo erro novamente.

Como comentei na candidatura, tenho certa experiência em lidar com pessoas e, principalmente, em ter que tomar decisões que desagradassem muitas delas. Já fui moderador de uma expressiva comunidade ainda no auge da rede social Orkut. o Plantão de Dúvidas Virtual, que tínhamos um formato bastante semelhante ao SOpt, adaptado às ferramentas disponíveis, de perguntas e respostas voltadas ao vestibular/ENEM; a comunidade contava com muito mais usuários que o SOpt e nunca tive problemas com a moderação lá. Pelo contrário, tínhamos excelência na moderação, o que garantia uma organização da comunidade a ponto de virarmos notícia em vários meios de comunicação como uma ferramenta base para quem estava na luta por uma vaga na universidade. Além disso, durante a graduação fui representante de turma, pessoa que responde por toda a turma perante a comunidade acadêmica (professores, direção, administração, etc), fui presidente do centro acadêmico do curso, pessoa que representa o curso inteiro (todos os alunos) perante a comunidade, e fui também representante dos discentes no colegiado, que é a entidade máxima em questão de decisões dentro de um curso de graduação. Também fui professor de robótica lecionando para crianças de 4 a 16 anos - e quem já teve que lidar com crianças e, principalmente os pais delas, sabe o que é isso :D

Hoje devo ser um dos usuários mais ativos do site. Ser moderador não irá mudar isso.

> 4. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

A estrutura do site te permite, para todos os fins práticos, ignorar o sistema de comentários. Para quase tudo existe um sistema melhor destinado para aquela finalidade, o que não significa que os comentários são inúteis e sem utilidade. Se um usuário permanece com dúvida em uma publicação pode utilizar os comentários em busca de um esclarecimento. Isso pode e deve continuar acontecendo.

Mas quanto à pergunta, julgo que as duas informações não devem ser avaliadas em conjunto. Se o usuário produz boas respostas ele estará colaborando com a comunidade e nada precisa ser feito quanto a isso. O problema se encontrará exclusivamente no mal uso ou comportamento nos comentários. Antes de qualquer ação, deve se analisar a origem do ocorrido. Se o usuário está insultando outros usuários, os comentários deverão ser prontamente excluídos e as partes envolvidas notificadas. Um quanto faltar com educação com outros usuários e outros, se necessário, de prolongar a discussão de forma desnecessária. Ninguém é obrigado a ficar quieto quando se é insultado, mas o melhor é ignorar publicamente e sinalizar para a moderação o comentário com insulto.

Se o comportamento do usuário se manter mesmo após notificações e conversas, acredito que outras ações deverão ser tomadas, como suspensão temporária do usuário. Não só como moderador, mas como usuário do site, devo prezar sempre pela saúde da comunidade. Se um usuário está se tornando tóxico, ele deve ser contido - mas não necessariamente eliminá-lo. Mostrar a ele como suas atitudes afetam toda a sociedade a sua volta e orientá-lo a mudar sempre é a melhor saída.

> 5. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Neste ponto, como um usuário qualquer. Se a ação foi tomada seja ela por um moderador ou pela própria comunidade existiu um motivo para tal. Não há como reagir sem conhecer o motivo. Ao discordar da ação, eu iria publicar minha opinião por algum meio e discutir com a comunidade e reagir somente se a comunidade concordar. O site Meta existe justamente para isso, bem como há o chat para discussões mais informais se não for nada grave. Participo ativamente nos dois como usuário, não seria diferente como moderador.

> 6. Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?

Nada disso deveria fazer diferença e acredito que eu consiga separar as coisas. Independente de quem seja o usuário, a moderação deve ser igual. Usuários que são conhecidos/amigos ou membros com alta reputação tendem a ser mais receptivos por entenderem melhor o funcionamento do site.

Quanto a usuário mais experientes, vejo que não é uma obrigação do moderador saber o que é o certo para a comunidade; somente é buscar saber o que é melhor e aplicá-la. Mesmo como moderador aprenderei muito com os usuários mais experientes.

> 7. Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

Já na minha participação como usuário busco investir mais tempo nas atividades de moderação que propriamente respondendo/perguntando. Como moderador isso não mudará, ou melhor, aumentará. Sendo moderador, as responsabilidades aumentam, demandando muito mais atenção em cada passo dado. Quanto a pontuação em reputação, por mais que novos usuários chegam com "sangue nos olhos" por aumentar a reputação, com pouco tempo de uso do site percebe-se que a reputação não passa de consequência do bom uso da ferramenta. Buscarei sempre colaborar em questão de conteúdo, mas priorizarei a questão de moderação.

> 8. É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

Quando isso ocorre com um moderador, acredito que ele está deixando de cumprir com seu papel. É um ciclo natural, de uns mais longos, outros talvez mais curtos. Um exemplo disso é o fato desta vaga para moderador ter sido aberta com a saída de um dos moderadores atuais. Quando acontecer comigo, terei o bom senso de pedir para sair e deixar o espaço para quem esteja com ânimo para colaborar mais, mas podem ter certeza que adiarei esse dia o máximo possível, senão nem teria me candidatado.

> 9. Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?
> 10. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Modéstia a parte, acredito ser um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário, sim, e isso não mudará em nada com o acréscimo do diamante - nem se caso eu não vencer a eleição. E acredito que essa minha participação ativa no site seja um ponto positivo. Dentre os 6 moderadores atuais, podemos ver ativamente - e com isso digo mais acessível à comunidade - 2 ou 3, dependendo dos dias. Isso naturalmente os sobrecarrega, independente se todos são ativos no site ou não. Sendo moderador eu pretendo colaborar com isso, estando disponível para quem precisar conversar com a moderação.

Acredito que isso esteja em conforme com as necessidades atuais, como descrito pelo Maniero em [Eleição Para Moderadores da Comunidade 2018](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/5878), conforme [Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/5878) e conforme [Quem são os moderadores do site e o que fazem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

---

Utilize os comentários abaixo caso queira perguntar alguma coisa ou acesse o chat [Eleição SOpt 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84205/eleicao-sopt-2018) para conversarmos melhor.

Comment: Um ótimo candidato. Não pertence às panelas e tem um ótimo conhecimento, tanto técnico quanto às coisas do site. Embora eu ache que não seja o mais simpático, creio que seria um bom moderador.

Comment: @sam Bom saber disso, irei trabalhar mais na minha simpatia :D

Comment: +1... gostaria muito de vê-lo moderador.

Answer (score 14):

## Victor Stafusa

### Quem sou eu

- Meu nome completo é **Victor Williams Stafusa da Silva**.
- Usuário ativo no SOpt e membro desde o primeiro dia (sou o usuário 132).
- Medalha de ouro na tag [image: medalha de ouro na tag Java], mas atuo no site como um todo e vou atuar ainda mais.
- Tenho mais de 50K pontos. Sou o 12º lugar geral, 5º se considerar apenas 2018.
- Sou brasileiro e moro em São Paulo - SP - Brasil.
- Formado em Ciência da Computação.
- Pós-graduação completa em Desenvolvimento Java.
- Doutorado interompido em Ciência da Computação.
- Pós-graduação em Gestão da Tecnologia da Informação.
- Professor universitário de linguagens de programação.
- Certificações SCJP 6, SCWCD 5, SCJA, SCBCD 5 e SCSNI.
- Funcionário público.

### Comportamento

- Normalmente sou calmo e ponderado. Poucas vezes esquentei com alguma coisa aqui mesmo quando atacado e dessas poucas vezes, a maioria foram no início. Não costumo agir por impulso, o que é muito importante na hora de moderar.
- Acredito que o moderador também é zelador do site. Mas além disso, é também um líder.

### Minhas propostas

- Lidar com flags e tarefas chatas de moderação.
- Limpeza e reorganização em várias tags.
- Converter mais respostas em comentários quando pertinente.
- Acalmar os ânimos quando as coisas ficarem mais acaloradas.

### Atitudes que vou mudar daqui para frente, sendo ou não eleito

- Frequentar ainda mais o chat, filas de análise e o meta.
- Dar mais chance para os novatos se sentirem melhor por aqui, especialmente os que fazem perguntas. Acredito que edição é melhor que fechamento. Obviamente, isso é bem diferente do que deixar que qualquer porcaria seja despejada aqui.
- Ser mais incisivo com a SE por melhorias na tradução do site.

## Minhas respostas ao questionário

---

> 1. É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?

> 2. Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?

Respondo às duas perguntas acima com uma só resposta, que a que se segue:

Com certeza entendo a cultura da comunidade e também os vícios e problemas que há nessa cultura (seria ilusão e hipocrisia dizer que ela é perfeita ou que não há problemas). Inclusive foi por causa disso que criei diversas postagens no meta:

- [Campanha: Fechamento justo e explicado. Reabertura justa e explicada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/132)
- [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132) e a maioria das respostas de lá.
- [Tarefas/exercícios de faculdade/curso de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6895/132)
- [Esta resposta minha sobre voto contra.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6889/132)
- [Esta resposta minha sobre votos de fechamento e perguntas com problemas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5711/132).
- Duas respostas na pergunta sobre [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

O que fez o SOen ser um sucesso e subir rapidamente ao primeiro lugar como a melhor comunidade de programação foi o fato de prezar-se pela qualidade das perguntas e respostas e também pelo valor futuro das mesmas. Posteriormente esse modelo de sucesso foi replicado em outras áreas ligadas ou não à TI e na língua portuguesa temos o SOpt. No entanto, isso também significa que perguntas mal-elaboradas ou que não se adequem ao modelo pergunta e respostas não tem futuro aqui.

Outra coisa que acredito ser um grande valor para o SOpt (e todos os sites semelhantes da rede SE) é a **edição**. Sou [fortemente favorável a isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2497/132).

Quanto ao fato de ver como "suporte técnico" e sobre a falta de experiência de usuários novos e cansaço dos antigos, falo sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7175/132). Para não me delongar muito, digo que a abordagem de ver o SOpt como um suporte técnico, um fórum, facebook, tweeter, slack, whatsapp, chat ou qualquer outra coisa que não seja o formato de pergunta e resposta como algo bastante nocivo e prejudicial.

Também digo que é importante orientar bem os nossos novos usuários, e não simplesmente tacar downvotes e fechamento sem ao menos algum comentário explicando e orientando. Já falei algo sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4500/132) e também em vários dos links que já coloquei acima.

---

> 3. Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

> 7. Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

> 8. É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

> 9. Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?

Estas quatro perguntas versam sobre o que se espera no dia-a-dia de um moderador e se eu terei tempo para fazer isso. Logo, respondo a todas elas de uma só vez.

Sei que grande parte do trabalho de moderação inclui:

- Lidar com uma pilha de flags que contém tudo que é coisa ruim.
- Buscar por engraçadinhos e encreiqueiros que estejam caçando problemas.
- Fechar perguntas horrorosas.
- Sumir com respostas que não respondem nada.
- Por vezes, ser o juiz e o carrasco que vai condenar alguém.
- Aguentar chororô de todo tipo de gente.
- Debater casos controversos e duvidosos com outros moderadores.
- Pensar no que pode ser feito para arrumar as coisas quando começam a desandar.

Poucas dessas coisas acima podem ser feitas efetivamente por usuários comuns, ainda mais se estiverem atuando sozinhos. Isso por si só já é um motivo para ter o diamante, pois se os moderadores que temos fossem o suficiente, não haveria a necessidade desta eleição estar sendo realizada. No mais, o SOpt precisa eleger um moderador que entenda a cultura e o funcionamento do site e da SE, e acredito que esse é o meu caso. Inclusive, as minhas propostas que enumero no início desta publicação dizem respeito exatamente a isso.

Sei que há casos que dão desânimo só de olhar, inclusive falo de alguns deles [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7175/132). A diferença é que como usuário normal, eu não tenho poder, recursos, autoridade ou autonomia para lidar efetivamente com muitas coisas, restando apenas o desgaste sofrido com o processo quando tento fazer alguma coisa para tentar arrumar os rumos. Com o diamante, isso é diferente, pois aí tem-se a autoridade, poder, recursos e autonomia.

Inclusive, fui questionado pelo Maniero na [página da minha candidatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-333580) (selecionar a aba de candidatura):

> E por que a decisão de atuar mais agora nessas coisas? Algum motivo para não ter feito antes? Por que precisa ser moderador para começar fazer?

Reitero então o que disse por lá:

> Em geral eu já fazia isso, mas quando me chateava acabava deixando de lado. Sendo um usuário comum não há tanto compromisso assim em fazer-se isso, diferente do caso de quando há um diamante ao lado do nome. No chat é porque não costumo ser muito conversativo, mas agora quero estar lá de forma mais ostensiva e sendo eleito teria um forte motivo para fazer isso.

Quanto ao tempo, sim terei. Eu já fico pendurado no SOpt por diversas horas do dia quase que todos os dias, embora muitas vezes faço isso em horários de pouco movimento. Assim sendo, pretendo tomar para mim bastante dessas atividades. Em muitos dias que acesso, acabo me frustrando por não encontrar nenhuma pergunta que eu saiba ou que eu possa responder, então como moderador, esse tempo tenderia a ser melhor aproveitado. É claro que se encontrar uma pergunta que eu saiba responder, continuarei a fazê-lo.

Eu como a maioria dos outros usuários do site incluindo moderadores, também tenho meus ciclos de atividade mais alta e mais baixa. Isso é natural. Nem por isso considero que alguns dos moderadores que frequentemente vejo online deixem de cumprir com sua tarefa, embora possa levar mais tempo às vezes.

Mesmo sendo usuário normal do site, também tenho meus períodos de atividade mais baixa e depois de todos eles, tive um período de atividade mais alta. Se nesses quase cinco anos que estou neste site, mesmo que tenha me afastado por alguns períodos, nunca me afastei dele de vez, não acho teria motivos para me afastar mais tendo o diamante.

---

> 4. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

> 6. Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?

Respondo as duas perguntas com uma só resposta, vez que são semelhantes.

Já houve no passado e há no presente exemplos reais de pessoas que produzem boas respostas, mas também diversas polêmicas, mas que felizmente são pontuais. Deve-se agir com paciência, avisando, conversando e orientando tal como seria com qualquer outro usuário. Se a pessoa está a ultrapassar a linha em demasia, toma-se uma providência tal como seria com qualquer outro usuário.

Para lidar com amigos, já fiz isso em alguns casos inclusive. Há uma pergunta deletada aqui no meta (não convém colocar o link, pois houve bons motivos para ser deletada) onde havia um conflito entre dois usuários de alta reputação daqui e eu tentei atuar meio como um mediador, tentando também manter a neutralidade. Também já me envolvi em polêmicas por defender usuários com baixa reputação em alguns casos.

A forma de se lidar com isso é manter sempre na cabeça o seguinte: Agir com imparcialidade, neutralidade e isonomia. Deve-se tentar imaginar o que seria se por trás dos nomes conhecidos com grande reputação, estivessem nomes desconhecidos com baixa reputação. E o contrário também, tentar imaginar como seria se por trás dos nomes desconhecidos de baixa reputação, estivessem nomes conhecidos de alta reputação. Se entre as duas abordgens houver algo significativamente diferente, faz-se necessário pensar se de fato estaria agindo com neutralidade, imparcialidade e isonomia.

Também acredito no princípio jurídico da ampla defesa e do contraditório. Qualquer usuário que esteja sendo atacado, acusado ou julgado tem o direito de se defender e ser defendido, o de dar a sua versão sobre os fatos e o de ter as suas manifestações ouvidas e avaliadas de forma justa.

---

> 5. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Conversando com esse moderador. Se ele discordar, posso chamar outros moderadores para debater. Acredito que um moderador sozinho não pode se sobrepor a outro moderador também sozinho. No entanto vários moderadores em acordo podem se sobrepor a um moderador sozinho.

Felizmente esses casos tendem a ser raros. Na maioria das vezes, o fechamento é justo e mesmo quando eu discordo, não acho que valha o esforço de reabrir, pois dificilmente o fechamento não é merecido. No caso de remoção, acredito que só ocorreria por algum motivo bastante grave.

Há também o caso onde a pergunta tenha sofrido significativas edições depois de fechada. Neste caso, se eu acreditar que tenham sido sanadas as razões que motivaram o meu colega ou a comunidade a fechá-la, posso reabri-la. Também levaria em consideração quaisquer manifestações do OP e de terceiros interessados na pergunta (especialmente daqueles que sabidamente conhecem como as coisas funcionam por aqui). No caso de dúvidas, posso até deixar alguns comentários explicando, mas é melhor deixá-la como está e só mudar a situação quando tiver certeza de que é o correto.

---

> 10. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Já deixei as minhas propostas no começo desta publicação e também na [página da minha candidatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-333580). Reitero aqui:

- Lidar com flags e tarefas chatas de moderação.
- Limpeza e reorganização em várias tags.
- Converter mais respostas em comentários quando pertinente.
- Acalmar os ânimos quando as coisas ficarem mais acaloradas.

Inclusive, fui questionado pelo Maniero na [página da minha candidatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-333580) (selecionar a aba de candidatura):

> Essas coisas específicas que diz pretender fazer (tags por exemplo) são com participação da comunidade? E dos outros moderadores? E se as pessoas não quiserem? Como vai lidar com isso? Em alguns casos você já demonstrou se fortemente contrário a algumas decisões de usuários com poderes de algum tipo de moderação ou diamante. Como acha que afetará sua moderação?

Reitero então o que disse por lá:

> Embora definitivamente há muito trabalho monocrático (você é quem mais sabe disso), não pretendo sair fazendo mudanças grandes sem no mínimo um consenso entre os moderadores e a anuência da comunidade. Se a comunidade e/ou os demais moderadores se oporem a mim, devo respeitar, pois é assim que a democracia funciona e é assim que o SOpt e todos os sites da SE funcionam, caso contrário seria abuso de poder. Aliás, considero bom o fato de ter algumas opiniões fortes, pois ninguém vai querer alguém que não tenha opinião bem formada sobre nada ou que esteja mudando de ideia a toda hora ou que sempre tenha a opinião da maioria só para estar junto com a maioria.

---

### Outras perguntas feitas na [coleção de perguntas para moderador](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7330/132)

> Ser moderador também é ser um alvo preferencial de muitos usuários problemáticos. Inclusive, há usuários problemáticos com alta reputação. Como você lidaria com ataques de outros usuários que envolvam acusações e provocações contra você nos mais diversos cenários onde isso certamente vai acontecer se você for eleito?

Regra número 1: Cabeça fria e não agir de forma compulsiva.

Depois, em parte eu lidaria tal como faria sendo usuário normal. Conversa e downvote se for pertinente. Voto de fechamento não ainda porque o que vem do moderador tem poder decisivo monocrático. Às vezes, deixar o usuário problemático falando sozinho por algum tempo pode resolver.

Acusações e ataques que partam para insultos e comportamento manifestamente ofensivo são mais fáceis de lidar, toma-se a mesma ação que seria tomada se o alvo fosse qualquer outro usuário.

Se a coisa ficar muito quente, pode ser o caso de chamar um outro moderador para avaliar. Se acontecer com algum outro moderador, posso ser chamado para tomar uma decisão também.

---

> Como você acha que deve agir um moderador caso tenha que lidar, por algum motivo, com uma pergunta que tenha uma resposta dele mesmo, ou até mesmo que a pergunta seja dele mesmo? Por exemplo, a comunidade fecha uma pergunta, mas o moderador acha que ela tem potencial e reabre a pergunta. Sendo que tem uma resposta desse moderador nessa pergunta.

Faria o que já delineei [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/132) há mais de três anos atrás. O primeiro passo é tentar falar com quem fechou a pergunta e inquirir acerca das razões de fechamento. Isso é algo que eu faria e já faço como usuário normal. A diferença é que eu não posso dar o voto de reabertura porque ele é decisivo e poderia ser abusivo. Se nada se resolver, posso pedir para um outro moderador avaliar, vez que não teria mais posição de neutralidade nesse caso.

Answer (score 5):

### Guilherme Nascimento

- Comecei a aprender os conceitos de programação aos 14 anos de idade, hoje com 30 anos
- Participo do site ativamente a quase 4 anos, apesar de ter conta aqui antes disto.
- Sou o top 5 do SOpt
- Atuo ativamente nas tags [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) e outras mais especificas.
- Minha avaliação nas eleições:

  - pontuação do candidato 40/40
  - reputação >= 20k
  - medalhas de moderação: 8/8
  - medalhas de edição: 6/6
  - medalhas de participação: 6/6

Como desenvolvedor criei um framework PHP e um kit de desenvolvimento front-end de grids, navbar e outros utilitários, semelhante ao uikit e bootstrap.

### Minha atuação na comunidade

Respondi a muitas perguntas e focando geralmente nos detalhes e qualidade sempre sendo CONTRA A GAMBIARRAS:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento

No META também sou bastante ativo, pode observar bem em:

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento

---

### Respostas

> 1. É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?

Isso mesmo sem ser moderador eu já faço, vai de caso a caso, tem usuário que você consegue orientar e comentar e ele entende, tem usuário que não entende, não por mal, mas realmente por falta de experiencia, esses geralmente eu edito a pergunta para ele e fico na esperança dele entender, não tem "como motivar", cada pessoa que participa do site é unica, cada um tem um interesse proprio, não tem o que fazer além do que já faço. Todavia ao meu ver isso é função da comunidade toda e não uma atuação exclusiva de moderadores, todos moderamos.

> 2. Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?

Entendo, aliais afirmo que entendo mais que a maioria dos participantes desta eleição, claro que tem exceções nas eleições aqui que entendem muito bem a "cultura" da comunidade, infelizmente outros não, mas o foco não é falar sobre isto, é falar sobre a atuação de moderadores e sobre o que trouxe o SO ao relativo sucesso.

Eu já atuai como moderador em fóruns, até no iMasters, isto desde 2004, mas nunca senti o conforto de um ambiente com respostas de qualidade ficarem em evidencia, quase tudo ia para o limbo, pois em fóruns geralmente o bom conteudo é visto só como mais um suporte técnico, já no SOen e no SOpt, notei que isso era feito de forma diferente, o sistema de gamefication, apesar de odiado por alguns e as vezes mal usado, ajudou a deixar em evidencia as respostas bem elaboradas e que servirão para futuros visitantes falando de coisas que até alguns acreditavam ser desnecessárias.

A comunidade cresceu por causa deste conteúdo de qualidade que ficava mais evidente aos novatos, é claro que infelizmente tem gente que confunde a comunidade/site com um "suporte técnico" e acredita realmente que ajudar usuários com respostas gambiarras e até erradas, mas que resolvem parcialmente o problema é ser util/bom, infelizmente **a "cultura da gambiarra"** também esta presente no site graças a uma turma que não entende coisas como:

- Funcionar não significa que esteja correto
- A "fila de analises" é um local que deve ter conhecimento antes de votar

Então temos um mesclado da cultura que nos levou a ser referencia junto a uma cultura de gambiarras que geralmente não aceitam criticas construtivas, meu foco como moderador (fora as tarefas administrativas) vai ser tentar dar um norte e minimizar atuações ruins de certas que prejudicam outros usuários novatos que acreditam ter obtido uma boa resposta, quando obtiveram algo problematico.

> 3. Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

**Sim.** Tanto entendo o sentido de desagradar todos, que já defendi moderadores diamantes que sofreram ataques de usuários que não entendem a comunidade e gostam de se fazer de vitima e por mais que ainda sim a atividade moderador diamente seja obscura para todos os candidatos, acredito que eu e mais 2 ou 3 participantes desta eleição entendemos o suficiente para "começar" a atuar como moderadores, infelizmente também nesta eleição também temos quem pensa que ser moderador é o mesmo que ser anfitrião em uma festa.

> 4. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

- Na primeira situação de problema que ele causasse eu comentaria direto na postagem que ele estiver causando problemas
- Se tornar a se repetir tentaria a comunicação fora da vista da comunidade (por exemplo email)
- Se insistir, então a conversa acabaria ali e solicitaria o contato com outros moderadores diamante para juntos tomarmos uma decisão sobre deixar o usuário bloqueado ou não
- Se nenhum moderador me der retorno em um tempo razoavel eu mesmo iria avaliar o grau do problema e optaria por um tempo de bloqueio para o usuário, as vezes o cantinho da *"disciplina é necessário"*

> 5. Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?

Ao meu ver todos somos iguais, se esta causando problemas seguirei o mesmo que citei na pergunta anterior, claro que existem diversos tipos de problemas, não existe uma formula exata para resolver o problema, o que posso fazer é analisar caso a caso e amizade é no chat e se formos tão amigos assim espero que esse entenda melhor que qualquer um a minha atuação como moderador e que não posso passar o pano para ninguém.

> 6. Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

Já abri mão de ganhar reputação faz muito tempo, o meu foco é tentar evidenciar respostas de qualidade e tornar o site uma fonte o mais segura e confiável possível para ajudar pessoas com duvidas, nos ultimos tempos as respostas gambiarras e de pessoas que pensam entender de algo só porque leram outra resposta e copiaram algo mudando um pouco o código cresceu demais, estou buscando tornar a comunidade melhor e vou dar a chance destes que fazem ainda alguma bagunça no site se redimirem. Mas sobre o score, abro mão o foco é a qualidade do site.

> 7. É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

Vou ser sincero, eu e nem ninguém prevê o futuro, se algo estiver dando muito problema mesmo é porque tem algo grave e deve ser resolvido se isso de enxugar gelo começar a ocorrer com muita frequência eu vou é tentar combinar algo com os moderadores, mas se nada resolver então vou tentar atuar por conta para resolver e se ainda sim o problema for incontrolável é porque só existe uma resposta, o site esta fora do controle quando não deveria e então o melhor é eu deixar o cargo, porque se o sistema me impede de atuar significa que moderador não tem utilidade aqui e por isso não teria sentido eu continuar. De qualquer forma não sei o que vai acontecer se eleito, vou fazer o que acredito ser melhor.

> 8. Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?

Existem muitos problemas ocasionados por usuários que não entendem a comunidade, e não é só um, é uma lista, aliais quase toda semana tem um novo, meu foco vai ser "tentar" conter os problemas que afetam a qualidade, principalmente relacionado a postagens que são evidentemente duplicatas, mas o ego inflado de alguns respondedores os impede de aceitar isto, pois o foco desse povo não é a qualidade e sim o egocentrismo, minha atuação vai ser tentar direcionar a comunidade para a qualidade e se possível deixa-la mais atraente para alguns veteranos otimos que deixaram de participar com suas otimas respostas (por vários motivos deixaram de atuar). O foco de minha atuação será a qualidade da comunidade e suas respostas.

Eu também (não sei se será possivel) quero dar um jeito na fila de analises, aonde a maioria atua incorretamente, o que até desmotivou muitos bons usuários de participarem, mas isto eu não sei se será possivel resolver, não tenho detalhes sobre isto, somente staff e moderadores devem poder me dar um norte sobre existir ou não a possibilidade de bloquear a atuação de alguns péssimos colaboradores na FILA DE ANALISE.

> 9. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Acho que acabei respondendo isto nas outras perguntas, mas para resumir será:

- Melhorar a qualidade do site de forma geral
- Se possível melhorar a fila de analises
- Tornar a comunidade atrativa novamente a alguns participantes excepcionais que deixaram de participar no passado
- Bloquear usuários problemáticos que infelizmente espantaram alguns bons colaboradores, mas antes de bloqueá-los irei dar-lhes a chance de se redimirem.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, me chamo Ricardo Pontual, um pouco sobre mim:

Tenho 45 anos, moro em São Paulo atualmente e trabalho com TI há mais de 20 anos.
Inicialmente participei mais do SO, mas no último ano tenho me dedicado quase que 100% no SOPT.

Minhas repostas (tardias.. rs):

> É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por
>   preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas
>   perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários
>   novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais
>   veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou
>   apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua
>   visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses
>   usuários?

Acredito que como moderador visitar as perguntas novas é algo fundamental, verificando não só qualidade, mas duplicatas, spams, etc, mas também acompanhar os comentários, que muitas vezes podem gerar flames e espantar novos usuários.
Mas vejo também que isso é algo que depende também no SO e não apenas dos moderadores. Fazer com que os usuários façam o tour antes de fazer perguntas entre outras coisas é uma boa ação. Acho que criar uma pontuação ou medalhas para comentários contrutivos seja uma outra alternativa para contornar isso. Premiar usários que efetivamente fazem comentários instrutivos e construtivos deve melhor esse problema, sem necessariamente que haja intervenção do moderador, pretendo sugerir isso.

> Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande
>   ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para
>   perguntas com algumas funções a mais?

Acompanho o SO há mais de 3 anos e o SOpt há 2 e acredito entender bem o funcionamento do SO.
Acredito que o moderador deve ter tempo para interar onde os demais usuários com mais privilégios não podem. O moderador deve pensar estratégias e fomentar isso entre os demais usuários, e não apenas executar ações mais pontuais.

> Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas
>   imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em
>   https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar
>   quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais
>   "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para
>   si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar
>   comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não
>   dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo
>   para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser
>   feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é
>   propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade
>   funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não
>   economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

Li o post no meta, e também acompanho várias discussões, embora nem sempre participe de todas. Acredito que ser firme não é ser enérgico necessariamente, é tomar a ação necessária no tempo certo. Ninguém pode agradar a todos, mas é importante zelar pelo bem estar da maioria, que é garantir que as coisas funcionem bem aqui. Sempre fui uma pessoa calma e moderada, mas não indecisa ou apática. Acredito que, diferente de outros candidatos com mais tempo e atividades aqui no site do que eu, a minha falta "experiência" de SO por assim dizer, comparada a eles não é um ponto negativo se você ve pelo lado que não tenho clima ruim com nenhum outro usuário. Provavelmente será mais fácil para mim conseguir a simpatia e apoio de vários usuários, que hoje já não tem uma situação tão amistosa. Claro que ao exercer a moderação posso cair na mesma situação, mas acho que esse clima cordial vai ajudar muito qualquer moderador que esteja chegando agora.

> Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas,
>   mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos
>   comentários?

Acredito que conversar é sempre a melhor opção antes de uma ação. Ninguém está aqui doando seu tempo 100% por gostar de tecnologia qualquer que seja, há sempre um interesse, na gamificação, nos benefícios que a reputação pode te trazer frente ao mercado, no networking, etc. Se conversar e tentar ajudar não forem suficientes, talvez seja necessário suspender por um tempo se for assim necessário para o bem da maioria, perde a comunidade com as boas respostas mas também perde o usuário, por todas as razões que fazem ele ser ativo no site.

> Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma
>   pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Conversar é o melhor caminho, acredito que sempre deve haver argumentos que não sejam de cunho pessoal que possam convencer a maioria sobre isso. De qualquer forma, os moderadores não podem entrar em atrito que vá além de uma discussão por uma pergunta, evitar isso é algo que pessoas equilibradas devem conseguir.

> Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na
>   hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro
>   da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que
>   você no site?

Respeito as pessoas em primeiro lugar, e depois seu papel, nao vejo problema em receber conselhos e ouvir opiniões de outros usuários que não sejam moderadores, mas ser imparcial é imprescindível para quem tem algum poder de arbitrar e tomar decisões, se eu não puder agir assim, nem me candidataria a moderador. 
Já recebi vários comentários e alertas de usuários daqui, sobre minhas respostas, duplicatas e opiniões controversas e sempre dei ouvidos, não tenho problema com isso e acho saudável.

> Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar
>   seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação
>   extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade,
>   como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar
>   reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

Não dá pra mentir e dizer que vou fazer as mesmas atividades e ainda as de moderador, provavelmente vou responder menos perguntas, que é o que mais faço aqui, e pode ser visto no meu ranking nesse ano [#9 ranking](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/526/year/pt-stackoverflow). Hoje participo mais do site por conta de ter meu tempo bem organizado, pretendo continuar assim, modelando novamente para atender as atividades de moderador.

> É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos
>   enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando
>   um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e
>   sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo
>   o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere
>   que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

Além dos problemas que conhecemos, a maioria já comentada no Meta, surgem coisas novas o tempo todo, tempos que nos adaptar. Um moderador não trabalha sozinho, são um time. Trabalhar como um time é essencial, por isso precisam se comunicar para que um ajude o outro, seja com horários, ajuda, problemas específicos, acredito que a colaboração vai fazer com que a moderação funcione e todos possam seguir com suas ideias e propostas. Trabalho em equipe é fundamental.

> Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que
>   você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não
>   faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?

Acredito que sangue novo faça bem. Me juntar aos moderadores vai permitir que eu aprenda mais e ao mesmo tempo ajude os moderadores com novas ideias, novas ações, ajude a lidar com usuários que eles já estão com problemas há um tempo, tudo isso uma pessoa nova pode agregar.

> Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você
>   pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a
>   isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores
>   nesse ponto?

Acho que um problema que mais estamos enfrentando atualmente é em relação à qualidade dadas perguntas e respostas de novos usuários em especial.
Algumas coisas podem ajudar:
-  Acompanhar as perguntas de usuários novos, incluir comentários sobre o tour, como criar um exemplo verificável e ser amistoso;
-  Votar nas perguntas bem elaboradas, incentivando os usuários a melhorar;
-  Criar um post no META com sugestões para os usuários, por exemplo como incluir um código no sqlfiddle, dotnetfiddle, codepen, etc, coisas que ajude a demonstrar da melhor maneira os problemas;

Answer (score 2):

## Felipe Augusto de Almeida

Apesar de ter menos pontuação que os outros candidatos, estou em processo de transição (terminando IC e faculdade) e conseguirei despender mais tempo na comunidade.

Acredito que o meu comportamento e ideias podem contribuir grandemente para a comunidade.

> 1. É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?

O problema citado é um ciclo vicioso, mas que pode ser quebrado. Os usuários novatos e preguiçosos sempre existirão, entretanto deixar que as suas ações afetem a comunidade é algo evitável, logo conseguimos ver que as ações bem provavelmente está na conscientização da reação da comunidade sobre os efeitos que ela causa ao responder um usuário novato/preguiçoso.

Como solução, especificamente falando, eu incentivaria uma explicação/discurso mais específico para cada situação, ao invés de apenas fornecer um link de como se deve perguntar, seria interessante dizer alguma parte desse link já no comentário, algo como: "Fornecer o código que você está usando atualmente pode nos ajudar a conseguir analisar melhor a questão.", sempre tentando ser simpático sobre a situação. Eu sei que a paciência é algo complicado, e repetir o exercício pode ser desgastante, mas acredito também que seja questão de cultura e costumes.

> 2. Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?

A cultura da comunidade, relacionando com a pergunta anterior, tem relação direta com o comportamento da mesma, com a qualidade das relações, continuidade da troca de conhecimento e prazer sobre se relacionar com a comunidade. Eu diria que mais importante do que conhecimento técnico.

> 3. Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

Eu sempre consegui fazer várias tarefas simultâneas (ensino médio, técnico e aulas de guitarra/ faculdade, iniciação científica e trabalho), e agora pretendo começar uma nova fase, que inclui a contribuição na comunidade. Isso demonstra minha organização e empenho nas tarefas realizadas, bem como minha responsabilidade.

Entendo sobre os deveres dos moderadores, da responsabilidade que eles devem chamar e da cultura que devem pregar, e acredito que minha personalidade, cultura e responsabilidade estão alinhados com os mesmos.

> 4. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Acredito que independente da contribuição técnica fornecida nas boas respostas e nos comentários, seria interessante sempre tentar, educadamente, fornecer feedbacks sobre os comentários sinalizados. A comunidade é mais importante do que o indivíduo particular, sendo assim, um comentário que pode influenciar na comunidade inteira deve ser sim, tratado como qualquer outro, independente de quem seja.

> 5. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Conversaria pessoalmente com ele, tentando sempre com educação e racionalidade entender os motivos que o levaram a tomar tal decisão, acredito que tudo é possível resolver com educação, racionalidade e bom senso.

> 6. Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?

Deve ser perfeita, ou pelo menos, tendendo à perfeição, a falta de imparcialidade pode levar à problemas, como a influencia nas votações positivas/negativas, falta de feedbacks etc.

Eu me daria com esse membro com um imenso prazer, pois adoro aprender e seria bem interessante receber feedbacks e conseguir aprender de alguém com maior experiência/conhecimento.

> 7. Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

Pretendo separar todos os dias, pelo menos 3h por dia moderando, e aos finais de semana o dobro.

A reputação em termos de pontuação e medalhas é apenas o *gamification* do Stackoverflow, o verdadeiro prazer está em pensar que você está contribuindo para a comunidade, sendo assim, não faria diferença, é claro que uma pergunta com muitos votos soa como algo bem interessante, mas quando conseguimos ter essa visão de comunidade e contribuição, as medalhas/pontuação passam a ter menos valor.

> 8. É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

Com certeza ele não estará cumprindo o que se propôs, pois ser moderador inclui, com certeza, estar presente na comunidade. Caso acontecesse comigo (o que acho bem improvável), eu tentaria consertar o que estivesse errado, seja minha presença, seja meu desempenho na comunidade, pediria feedbacks externos de diferentes pessoas. E caso não funcionasse eu pediria para sair.

> 9. Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?

Com os poderes de moderador eu conseguiria espalhar a cultura de respeito, paciência e dedicação para tornar a comunidade um lugar melhor. Acredito que a cultura seja um pilar que pode guiar todos os outros, e acredito que tenho essa cultura.

> 10. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Eu não acompanho o desempenho dos outros moderadores, mas percebi que alguns colocam comentários muito sucintos sobre o que poderia melhorar em uma pergunta/resposta e poderia acrescentar e ensinar mais à quem a realizou.

Eu pretendo me empenhar em detalhar esses casos e influenciar culturalmente na comunidade.

Answer (score -10):

### Quem sou eu?

- Nome: David Sammuel
- Apelidos usados no SOPT: [sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam) ou [dvd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam)

---

### Respostas para as perguntas

> 1. É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários). Essas
>    perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários
>    novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais
>    veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou
>    apenas indiferentes. Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua
>    visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses
>    usuários?

Não apenas recebendo esses novos, *preguiçosos* (sic) e inexperientes usuários com muita receptividade mas também instruindo-os a ambientalizarem-se no site, indicando a eles as documentações que são de leitura necessárias para uma participação dentro dos padrões que exige o SOPT.

Realmente há uma enxurrada de usuários que se encaixam nessa realidade, mas é preciso um esforço a mais, não só da moderação, mas também de usuários experientes, em fazer com que esses usuários se sintam bem recebidos para que possam continuar usando o site. Creio que a maioria deles não voltam mais por se sentirem rejeitados diante do impacto causado pelo fechamento ou votos negativos de perguntas ou respostas mal elaboradas. A minha pretensão é acolher da melhor forma esses usuários de forma com que eles se sintam bem recebidos e motivados, apontando os problemas e orientando-os de forma amigável, para que o número de usuários ativos seja cada vez maior.

> 2. Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico
>    para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?

Entendo perfeitamente a cultura da comunidade e o que a tornou grande em termos de referência, mas acho que em números ainda não seja tão grande assim. Apesar de ter milhares de usuários cadastrados, vejo que o número de usuários participativos ainda é modesto. Em pouco mais de 1 ano de participação diária bem ativa, vejo que há um número muito pequeno de usuários com intensa atividade.

Não creio que moderador seja suporte técnico. Ele, além de ser um usuário como qualquer outro, possui atribuições e deveres a mais, como impõe o status da função, além de agir como um líder e dar exemplo.

> 3. Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em
>    https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar
>    quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais
>    "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para
>    si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar
>    comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não
>    dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação. Você entende isto? Terá tempo
>    para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser
>    feito? A promessa é realista? A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é
>    propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade
>    funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não
>    economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

A questão de tempo para mim não é problema. Passo praticamente o dia todo no SOPT, muitas vezes até altas horas da madrugada, onde o movimento é praticamente nulo. E faço isso há mais de 1 ano quando me tornei um usuário ativo. Sem o diamante um usuário pode contribuir muito (talvez até mais que um moderador diamante) e não carregar a responsabilidade que o diamante exige, porém, minha pretensão é contribuir para além do usuário comum, seja na parte burocrática, moderação, mediação de problemas etc., tudo de forma a dar exemplo e respaldo à altura da exigência da função.

*"Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento"*. Não creio que seja bem assim. Acho que um moderador pode construir de forma positiva ou negativa a sua imagem. Claro que sempre poderá desagradar alguém com alguma ação, mas se tudo for feito de forma clara e com diálogo, o moderador constrói a sua imagem de forma positiva, mas se for um tirano que usa a sua posição privilegiada em termos de *poderes* que um usuário comum obviamente não possui, se torna um moderador detestável.

> 4. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações
>    nos comentários?

Depende do que sejam essas discussões (embora não seja permitidas discussões prolongadas nos comentários), mas pelo teor da pergunta creio que refere-se a bate-boca ou desavenças. Bem, eu chamaria esse usuário em um chat para entender melhor e resolver o eventual problema que o leva a isso, instruindo-o caso haja alguma falta ou violação dos Termos de conduta, tudo com diálogo, atenção e imparcialidade. Já me deparei com muitas situações de desacatos gratuitos e não provocados (eu mesmo já fui diversas vezes vítima dessas situações), mas acredito que tudo com um bom diálogo pode ser resolvido. Se o usuário produz boa respostas ele contribui de forma positiva, e não apenas ele mas todos merecem atenção e respeito.

> 5. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Não faria nada. Até hoje não vi nenhuma pergunta fechada ou removida por parte de um moderador forma que eu discordasse. Mas se acontecesse de eu discordar por algum motivo, eu apenas lhe informaria esse motivo, mas a decisão de manter fechada ou removida a pergunta fica a critério do moderador que o fez.

> 6. Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro
>    da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que
>    você no site?

Acho que o moderador tem por obrigação tratar a todos com imparcialidade, independentemente de ser amigo ou pela reputação, como venho sempre pregando. É comum as pessoas quando ocupam uma função ou cargo privilegiado tratarem seus amigos de forma diferenciada, mas acho isso incorreto. Claro que a forma de diálogo entre amigos é diferente, mas ao tratar de questões do site as ações do moderador deve ser totalmente imparcial e não deve ser levado em conta o fato de ser amigo. O que é certo é certo, o que é errado é errado, amizades à parte.

> 7. Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma
>    ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da
>    comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir
>    mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

Como já dito, passo, muitas vezes, 8, 12, 15 horas diárias no site. É um tempo razoável para conciliar atividades de moderação com responder a perguntas. Aliás, as duas coisas podem andar juntas, mas ao meu ver, sempre dando prioridade às atividades da função de acordo com a demanda, deixando as atividades de responder perguntas em segundo plano. Mas creio que isso não seja problema para mim, já que como dito, tenho bastante tempo disponível para conciliar as duas coisas.

> 8. É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir
>    afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto
>    ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará
>    cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que
>    considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

Essa pergunta não vou responder porque me pareceu muito vaga. Quais seriam esses problemas?

> 9. Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já
>    não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?

Minha pretensão ao ♦ é ajudar na parte burocrática/administrativa, além de poder resolver questões a cargo da moderação ♦ de forma mais justa, dando exemplo à comunidade. Quando se é um usuário comum e faz muito pela comunidade, isso não é visto (pelo menos no meu caso), mas com um ♦ ao lado do apelido, você se torna mais visto e as suas boas ações acabam sendo exemplo. Meu foco principal, além de exercer as funções do cargo, é procurar fidelizar novos usuários, para que o site tenha cada vez mais usuários ativos e de qualidade.

> 10. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a
>     isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores
>     nesse ponto?

Parte dessa pergunta foi respondida na pergunta anterior, apenas quero acrescentar que um dos problemas que o SOPT tem é a questão das *panelinhas*. Os usuários da *panela* podem falar o que querem, muitas vezes em tons agressivos, debochados ou irônicos. Quem não é da *panela*, se for se defender ou usar da mesma linguagem, é de pronto rechaçado e colocado numa espécie de *lista negra* dos panelas. Como moderador pretendo combater essa prática, chamando a atenção do autor de qualquer conteúdo dessa natureza, independente de sinalização, seja de usuário veterano ou novo. Mas farei isso de modo gentil, e não com arrogância ou arbitrariedade.

Por isso anseio muito que o número de usuários ativos cresça, pois desta forma a panelinha que se formou no SOPT tende a ser sufocada e o site será um lugar bem melhor para todos, não apenas pros *panelas*. Felizmente não sou o único a pensar assim, já vi inúmeros comentários de diversos usuários apontando para a mesma direção, de que existe uma *panelinha* formada e que, lamentavelmente, até moderador(es) diamante está(ão) envolvido(s).

Comment: Julgo que deveria ser mais explicito na questão da *"panelinha"*. A quê e a quem se está referindo?

Comment: Pois não. _Panelinha_ é um termo que ninguém gosta de ler, eu tb não gosto. Mas o que vejo em muitos casos me parece ser mesmo. Já vi casos em que até más respostas de membros da panela recebem uma enxurrada de votos positivos. Além de outras questões já bem discutidas em outras ocasiões que nem vou entrar no mérito por não ser o caso. Também não posso citar nomes porque não se deve expor usuários. Não tem problema algum pra mim ser taxado de chato, encrenqueiro ou receber votos negativos nas minhas colocações. Vou continuar falando o que vejo, de forma educada como venho fazendo.

Comment: Tem que dizer os nomes e mostrar os casos. Ao afirmar que *"até moderador(es) diamante está(ão) envolvido(s)."* tem mesmo de o fazer. Se não, como pode ter você condições de ser moderador? Deixar insinuações no ar, sem as concretizar, é muito pouco leal e democrático.

Comment: Deixar insinuações no ar até mesmo moderadores o fazem, como um deles há um tempo atrás disse que alguns usuários não mereciam estar nesta lista: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all   ...acho essa afirmação péssima até pra um usuário comum, quanto mais um moderador que devia dar exemplo.

Comment: Penso que você deveria focar mais nos objetivos que tem caso se torne moderador do que fazer acusações vagas, sem citar nomes e pior ainda, sem provar nada. Um moderador não pode entrar com esse pensamento, porque ele dá a entender que será apenas mais uma pessoa tóxica com poder na mão, e acredito que a SE não quer isso, e nem a comunidade. Recomendo que reveja esse detalhe na sua apresentação,  apenas como dica mesmo, pois acho que isso desvirtuou completamente o objetivo aqui, que é conhecermos melhor sua proposta caso se eleja.

Comment: @Articuno Vc tb já foi muito tóxico em algumas ocasiões, não se lembra? Se vc mudou a sua postura (e quero acreditar que sim), ótimo, seria um excelente moderador, se continua com o mesmo descontrole, é preocupante vc ter algum poder nas mãos (como diz). (Esse termo "tóxico" é ótimo rs.. vou passar a usar tb).

Comment: Bom, o candidato aqui a moderador é você, não eu, acho isso já define bem as prioridades aqui.

Comment: Convencer panelas é a mesma coisa de tentar fazê-los mudar de religião ou time favorito. Se não tiver um local discreto onde essas questões possam ser passadas a limpo é complicado, vão sempre ficar impressões que nunca condizem com a realidade. Eu não guardo más impressões de nenhum desses usuários que me "perseguem", embora tenha muitos motivos pra isso. Só acho feio a prática da panelinha, que vai de encontro com o propósito básico do site.

Comment: Ter um local discreto onde essas questões possam ser passadas a limpo não seria montar uma panelinha?

Comment: Outra coisa que eu gostaria de entender é porque você tem dois apelidos, pode me explicar?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Olá Roberto. Não necessariamente. Um local onde as pessoas envolvidas tivessem tempo e disposição de analisar as coisas de forma isenta, sem que pudesse expor nenhum usuário. Não gostaria de expor nenhum usuário publicamente, mesmo não concordando, não desejo que nenhum usuário sofra influência do que acho ou deixo de achar.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Posso explicar sim. Eu inicialmente usei muito o apelido "dvd", depois mudei pra "sam" por nenhum motivo específico. É comum alguns usuários mudarem de apelidos conforme ache melhor.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Mudar de apelido não muda quase nada. Quem é ativo e conhece o usuário sabe quem ele é mesmo com um apelido diferente. É apenas uma questão de gosto que o site proporciona.

Comment: Os panelas se protegem, se votam entre si, se tratam com toda delicadeza, e o resto dos usuários são tratados de forma diferente. Isso que não concordo. Já fui acusado de "não saber de nada" (isso em comentários, pasme), que "só quero arrumar treta", entre muitos outros comentários infelizes. Saiba, tudo que faço aqui eu foco o bem do site. Peguei a fama ruim que me colocaram por me defender de muitas acusações, mas eles, os panelas, falam o que querem e ninguém faz nada. No final eles são os bonzinhos e eu o malzinho. Nem mostram provas do que me acusam, só falam.

Comment: As eleições estão sendo boas, é a primeira vez que participo. Veja que muitos usuários compartilham da minha visão diante de muitos votos positivos na minha candidatura. Isso serve e servirá como base e convicção de que estou no caminho certo, ao contrário do que os panelas pensam. Os panelas não me querem como moderador porque é uma ameça à panela. Mas mesmo que eu não ganhe, vou continuar combatendo as panelas.

Comment: Vejo muita acusação e pouca prova. Acho que essa não é a atitude de um moderador que esperamos, que sai acusando mas não da nomes de ninguem, e nem provas. Se há algo errado acontecendo aqui e você sabe, omitir te torna tão cumplice quanto aqueles que estão participando diretamente. Por isso, insisto, se sabe algo de errado, deve reportar e não apenas denunciar ao vazio, pois parece que só está querendo atenção usando-se do vitimismo sobre algo que pode nem existir.

Comment: @Articuno Me mostre um local apropriado para isso.

Comment: @Articuno Até porque nem quero ressuscitar essas coisas. Mas se faz questão, me mostre o local e esteja lá que vou tentar buscar todas as provas de tudo.

Comment: @sam não é a mim q deve reportar, é a comunidade, eu sou um membro qualquer, assim como você e todos os demais. Só acho que esse tipo de coisa, dado a sua insistência em se desviar do tópico sobre "porque devo ser moderador" para falar disso já me parece suficiente para que exponha a comunidade. Caso não se sinta a vontade, procure um CM(comunity manager), e reporte a ele os fatos para que ele analise.

Comment: @Articuno Mas isso já foi feito na medida do possível. Se vc quer passar isso a limpo, me mostre o local que não exponha nenhum usuário. Estou disposto a lhe provar de tudo de que me acusam são paneladas.

Comment: Nenhum dos acusadores mostraram provas. Eu tenho que mostrar provas pra me defender? Sou idôneo e bem consciente das minhas atitudes. Em nenhum momento coloquei nenhum usuário no ridículo perante a comunidade, ao contrário do que fazem comigo.

Comment: Uma coisa é certa, este local é de candidatura, toda essa discussão, e até esta postagem tem a intenção de fazer coisas diferentes de propor algo para moderação. Atacar grupos de usuários deveria ser deixado para outro momento e outro local. Por favor use este local para o que ele foi determinado. Todas as ferramentas devem ser usadas da maneira correta no momento correto. E no momento correto, portanto após as eleições isso será tratado já que você insiste tanto em manter esse assunto ativo o tempo todo sem que nada possa ser feito. Ficar só reclamando não é uma atitude positiva e já deu.

Comment: @Maniero "_ficar só reclamando_".. uai, o que vc define "reclamar'?.. estou apenas dando satisfação aos comentários.

Comment: @Maniero Ah, entendi. Eles estão reclamando, e não eu. Se for isso, ignore meu comentário.

Comment: Sou amigo de todo mundo, até mesmo dos panelas. Procuro tratar bem a todos como seres humanos mesmo sendo isto aqui um lugar onde a melhor percepção que vc tem das pessoas são meros caracteres. Eles criaram uma imagem negativa de mim porque eles me atacaram e eu me defendi, ou eles falaram o que quiseram e eu questionei. Eu nunca ataquei ninguém aqui. Eles sim me atacaram com comentários infames. Eu nunca pensei em fazer isso, em denegrir a imagem de qualquer usuário. Acho que os panelas tem muito valor, exceto pelo fato de me perseguirem.